# Definition of "Application" from Microsoft and uC/OS

Tags: operating-system, embedded

**uC/OS-III User's Manual** says:

> The design process of a real-time application involves splitting the work into tasks(also called threads), and each task responsible for a portion of the job.

From this quote, we can inferred that an application consists of tasks (threads).

Also, In [Processes and Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/windows/desktop/ProcThread/processes-and-threads) from Microsoft:

> An application consists of one or more processes

Why different difinition?

Is this because uC/OS-III is for embedded environment and Microsoft is for PC environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a PC environment, a process is basically the same thing as a program. A process has an address space - a chunk of virtual memory that can only be accessed by that process. It consists of one or several threads, executing in the same address space, sharing the same memory. Different threads can run on different CPU cores, executing simultaneously.

On embedded RTOS systems, we don't really have all the dead weight of a hosted system process. Traditionally, RTOS therefore speaks of tasks, which is essentially the same thing as a thread. Except most microcontrollers are still single core, so the multi-tasking is simulated through task switches, everything running on one core. Older PC worked in the same manner.

Traditional microcontrollers don't have virtual memory, but addresses physical memory addresses directly. Therefore anything running on the microcontroller can access anything, by default.

Nowadays, upper-end embedded systems and hosted system are smeared together, as are the concepts. High-end microcontrollers have memory mapping units (MMU) capable of setting up virtual address spaces. PC programmers trinkle down into embedded systems and start looking for threads. And so on. The various concepts are blurring.

Comment: It is not true to say "multi-tasking is simulated".  A single core scheduler does not support parallel / concurrent execution, but that is not necessarily the purpose of a real-time scheduler or the aim of multi-tasking .  Rather it is to allocate CPU time to tasks in order to deterministically meet deadlines.  The purpose of a general-purpose OS scheduler is to allocate CPU time "fairly" by either timeslicing (simulated concurrency) or allocating execution to execution units (true concurrency).  An RTOS is about getting stuff done on-time rather then apparent concurrency.

Comment: @Lundin Let me make a conclusion based on your comment. 1. The term "process" is used in multi-core environment which has virtual memory mechanism. 2. If no virtual memory support, it should name task rather than thread.

Comment: @Clifford A single core scheduler does support concurrent from wiki [Concurrent computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing#Introduction). In introduction section

Comment: @AndyLin : The distinction between parallel and concurrent is perhaps not well defined.  I have made them synonymous, but in the terms of that article am referring to _parallel_.  I would use parallel computation to refer to low level capabilities such as SIMD, while concurrent is what that article calls parallel, and multi-tasking what the article calls concurrent.  I make a distinction between parallel, concurrent and multi-tasking - which I think is perhaps more useful.

Comment: @Clifford Sorry, I'm confused... According to Wiki: _In parallel computing, execution occurs at the same physical instant._ **and** _concurrent processes can be executed on one core by interleaving the execution steps of each process via time-sharing slices: only one process runs at a time._ **Last,** _multitasking is the concurrent execution of multiple tasks (also known as processes) over a certain period of time_

Comment: @Clifford Apparently, only multi-core capable of doing parallel computing, but I cannot distinguish between _concurrent_ and _multitasking_

Comment: @AndyLin : You don't need to; you just need to understand how the terms are used by whoever's writing you are reading.  You can use them how you wish, but you need to understand that others may not apply the same definitions to _any_ concept.  You are missing the main point perhaps that and RTOS does not _simulate_ multi-tasking - nitpicking about ambiguous terms is not the take-home here.

Comment: @Clifford Do you think there must be a reason for wiki to split multitasking and concurrent separately?

Comment: @Clifford I would believe it, but for now I'm not able to distinguish it

Comment: @Clifford Thank you. RTOS indeed is multi-tasking, not simulated

Comment: @AndyLin : Put it this way, multi-tasking does not depend on multiple execution units, and is not _simulated_ by an RTOS.  There are semantic differences between the terms used in _one_ article and me.  The article rightly defines what it means by these terms as have I, as any author might because usage may vary as time and technology move on and experience differs.  The article is by no means definitive, and in any discussion of the topic, you have to read in context and understand the intent of the author rather then try to match similar terms across authors and expect agreement!

Comment: @Clifford Great explanation! Multi-tasking only point out the feature of concurrency but do not specify how execution time are allocated.

Answer (score 2):

One (of several) dictionary definitions of "application" is:

> a program or piece of software designed to fulfil a particular purpose

In that sense both the Microsoft and uC/OS definitions are valid, it is simply that in the specific environments the structure, and execution environment of an application differ.  What they describe is what an application is composed of in the context of the specific platforms and execution environments.

I would suggest that "application" has no particular technical meaning; it is simply "the purpose to which a system or software is put" - it is just English, not a specific technical concept.

The boundary of an "application" is context dependent and a Desktop software application is a very different context that an embedded microcontroller application.  Equally you could draw your application boundary to encompass entire systems comprising many computers or processors running a variety of software and other equipment.

It means whatever the writer/speaker intends and can normally be inferred by the context.  Don't waste your time looking for *the one true definition* or be confused by different usage.